# Green's function in terms of logarithmic potential and energy of a measure

Tags: cv.complex-variables, potential-theory, green-function

Let $\mu$ be a finite (Borel) measure on $\mathbb{C}$ with compact support $K := \mbox{supp } \mu$.
The logarithmic potential associated to the measure $\mu$ is
\begin{equation}
\Phi_{\mu}(z) = - \int_K \log |z - w | d \mu(w).
\end{equation}
The energy of $\mu$ is given to be
\begin{equation}
I(\mu) = \int_K \Phi_{\mu}(z) d\mu(z) = - \int_K \int_K \log |z - w| d\mu(z) d \mu(w). 
\end{equation}
I could be missing something but it seems that in papers, people state
\begin{equation}
G_{K}(z, \infty) = I(\mu) - \Phi(z),
\end{equation}
where $G_K(z, \infty)$ is the Green's function defined on $\mathbb{C} \backslash K$ with a pole at $\infty$. I am wondering if anyone has any idea of how to show this because I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you stated cannot be true: Green function depends only on $K$, but your $\Phi_\mu$ is the potential of an arbitrary
measure on $K$. These formulas become true when $\mu$ is the
EQUILIBRIUM measure of $K$, that is the probability measure
which minimizes the energy among all probability measures supported by $K$. Potential $\Phi_\mu$ of this measure is constant on $K$, and this constant is equal to the energy.
For existence and uniqueness of such measure for a given $K$
see any textbook on potential theory.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the equilibrium measure, are you saying that if $\mu$ is an equilibrium measure, then $I(\nu) = \Phi_{\mu}(z)$ i.e. the potential equals the energy? If so, I don't see how that shows that $I_{\mu} - \Phi_{\mu}(z)$ is a Green's function?

Comment: @jcb2535: It is zero on $K$ and behaves like log at $\infty$, therefore coincides with the Green function by Maximum Principle.